# Google Play Console Package Name

Tags: android, android-studio, module, google-play-services

I have one application of Trivia, the package name is *es.test.triv.sh*, there are all things for play one player, I have add a new feature is a multi-player options, for this option I have use the [real-time](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) of google play, and I have to register the application with the package, here is the problem the implantation of this feature for multiplayers is on [new module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) of android and have a different package *com.stas.triv.mlt*

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings

On this point I have to set com.stas.triv.mlt or es.test.triv.sh?

Answer (score 2):

That package name always refers to the package name that Google Play console uses for your Application Id.

It used to be the one in the `manifest.xml` of your application

```
<manifest package="tv.potato.baked"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
    .
    .
```

But on (recent versions?) of Android Studio, this package is ignored, and the one defined in your application module's **build.gradle** is the one used:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tv.potato.baked"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        .
        .
        .
```

That package name also defines your app name in the playstore (look at the url), so once the app has been published for the first time it cannot be changed.